# Reset the primary key column with existing data in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an existing table where the first few rows have been deleted. Is it possible to reset the primary key so the existing data Id column changes back to 1,2,3..?

Comment: I think you should post it on StackOverflow

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it actualyl belongs either to stackoverflow or dba.stackexchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question belongs to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com).

For example you may find [renumber primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230006/renumber-primary-key) helpful

Answer (score 1):

This should work: DBCC CHECKIDENT(tableName, RESEED, 0).
The tip is from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205154600/http://geekswithblogs.net/TakeNote/archive/2007/11/30/117258.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please see Pinal Dave's blog post:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/15/sql-server-dbcc-reseed-table-identity-value-reset-table-identity/